# UILabel on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

When clicking the cell the label that was added to the cell is looking like in the picture attached, why is it???

http://s23.postimg.org/x4a7ffd7v/Untitled.png

this is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

int section = [indexPath section];
int row = [indexPath row];

int rowsInLastSections = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < section; i++) {
    rowsInLastSections += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}

Friend *friend = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:row + rowsInLastSections];

[friend setIndexPathInTableView:indexPath];

NSString *firstName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [friend firstName]];
NSString *lastName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [friend lastName]];

UIImageView *profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
[profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[friend imageUrl]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_pic_bg@2x.png"]];

UILabel *firstNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 230, 20)];
UILabel *lastNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 35, 230, 20)];
[firstNameLabel setText:firstName];
firstNameLabel.backgroundColor = table.backgroundColor;
[lastNameLabel setText:lastName];
lastNameLabel.backgroundColor = table.backgroundColor;

[cell.contentView addSubview:profileImageView];
[cell.contentView addSubview:firstNameLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lastNameLabel];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Please provide more details. Some code would be great...

Comment: You should post your code for the various `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

Comment: This the code for adding subviews to cell: :http://pastie.org/7729414

Comment: Please update your question with the text of the relevant code. Do not use links. And your screen shot can't be loaded into SO, it's in an unsupported format.

Comment: edit the post with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

add this code,

```
    for(UIView *view in cell.subviews){
        if([view isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            [(UILabel *)view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Comment: "1st of all I should say the way you do it is not good" How should I do it?

Comment: I don't add uilabels or any other component in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: I have changed the answer according to your code, please check the new answer.

Comment: for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    } //works for me, thanks!